# How to execute insert query using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a insert query using Entity Framework.

I have something like this:

```
Context.database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Insert into tableName Values({0},{1},{2}", param1, param2, param3)
```

but this is throwing an error

> incorrect syntax near '@p1'

What is this '@p1' ?

Comment: why are you writing SQL in entity framework to do an insert?

Comment: @DLeh yes I agree, I would use Sql Command only to execute stored procedures

Comment: i need to do something as dynamic insertion to tables where destination table might change. And they need entity framework. And they has said to use dynamic insertion queries

Comment: @p1 is the name of the first parameter in the sql script generated by EF.

Answer (score 17):

You missing the closing ) at the end of your INSERT.

It should be:

```
Context.database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Insert into tableName Values({0},{1},{2})", param1, param2, param3)
```

Alternatively, you could use the SqlParameter class:

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
    "Insert into tableName Values(@id, @firstName, @lastName)",
    new SqlParameter("id", id),
    new SqlParameter("firstName", firstName),
    new SqlParameter("lastName", lastName)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the obvious question why you are writing SQL, it seems you are missing a closing parenthesis, after the third `{2}` parameter:

```
Contex.database.ExecuteSQLCOmmand(@"Insert into tableName Values({0},{1},{2})",param1,param2,param3);
```

Then it is also a good practise to specify column names, like so:

```
Contex.database.ExecuteSQLCOmmand(@"Insert into tableName (col1, col2, col3) Values({0},{1},{2})",param1,param2,param3);
```